# How do I have Google Sheets automatically sort my rows based on the value in one of my columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google Sheets document(Link is at the end of this paragraph) which is meant to track accessories that people borrow. I have written a formula which updates the status of the entry as the following options: Good, Overdue, Returned, Returned Late, and Missing Info. My goal is to have the rows rearrange everyday to put the overdue items first, good status entries second, missing info third, and returned items last. I was able to something similar by using the built-in data filter. To do this I went to Data->Create Filter->Click on symbol on bottom right corner of status column->Sort Z-A. However this solution is manual as it isn't possible(to my knowledge) to run the filter function using the app script. Additionally, the order it sorts the rows isn't exactly what I need. I have written the following app script function to try to counter that however it doesn't seem to be working as imagined.

```
function swap(i, target, correctOrd){
  var link = decVar();
  var temp = 0;
  temp = link.mainSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, link.col).getValues(); 
  var oneRowCopy = link.mainSheet.getRange(i,1,1, link.col);
  var targetRow = link.mainSheet.getRange(target,1,1, link.col);
  oneRowCopy.copyTo(targetRow);
  temp.copyTo(targetRow); 
}

function reArrange(){
  var correctOrd = [].concat.apply([], getStatus());
  var link = decVar(); var temp = 0;
  for(var i = 2, j = 0; i<correctOrd.length+1; i++, j++){
    if(i != correctOrd[j]){
      swap(i, j, correctOrd);
      correctOrd[j] = i;
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the code can be found in the script part of the document shared.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15qaNHuMoVyEJmwR5pL9ruPFDeiNR60cKWLKxnfjaWko/edit?usp=sharing

Please let me know if you have any ideas on how something like this could be done or what I'm doing wrong with my code.
Thank you!

Comment: @I'-'I I added a description on how I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although inbuilt spreadsheet functions can be slow compared to Java script array functions, This custom built function can be used for your test case:

```
function OverdueGoodMissingReturned() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Main");
  var lr = sh.getLastRow();
  var lc = sh.getLastColumn();
  var irng = sh.getRange(1,9,lr,1).getValues(); //get col I (StatusColumn)
  var irngF = irng.map(flatten); //Flatten the 2D array
  function flatten(e) {return e[0];}
  var lr = irngF.indexOf(''); //Find actualLast Row (This is needed,because you filled all the rows with Data Validations)
  var rng = sh.getRange(2,1,lr-1,lc); //getWholeRange
  rng.sort(9); //Sort by the status Column 9,Default Sort is Good,Missing,Overdue,Returned
  var rv = rng.getValues();
  var irng = sh.getRange(1,9,lr,1).getValues();
  var irngF = irng.map(flatten);
  var O1 = irngF.indexOf('Overdue')+1; // Find first overdue
  var O2 = irngF.lastIndexOf('Overdue')+1; //Find Last overdue
  var mv = sh.getRange(O1+':'+O2); //getRange to move
  sh.moveRows(mv,2); //Move Overdue to Top
  }
```

Note: A lot of getRange calls could be cutoff ,If you don't fill the empty rows with data validations. `rng.sort` could also be cut short to `sheet.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom comparator for the `Array.prototype.sort()` method. Your comparator needs to return negative for when the first object comes before the second object, 0 when the two are interchangeable, and positive when the first comes after the second object.
To avoid a lot of nasty case considerations, this can be easily done by defining a "lookup table" which returns a numeric value for a given possible input value:

```
// Comparison object. Objects to come first should be ranked lower.
var ordering = {
    "Good": 5,                     // Will come last.
    "Missing Info": 2,
    "Overdue": 1,                  // Will come first.
    "Returned": 3,
    "Returned Late": 4,
};

var compareIndex = 1; // Column B data, for example
var sheetData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
sheetData.sort(function (row1, row2) {
  // If the compare value is not found in the comparison object, or is convertible to "false" (e.g. 0)
  // then the "|| 400" portion makes it default to a value of 400.
  var v1 = ordering[row1[compareIndex]] || 400;
  var v2 = ordering[row2[compareIndex]] || 400;

  return (v1 - v2);
});
sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetData.length, sheetData[0].length).setValues(sheetData);
```

By changing the values in the comparison object, you can change the order in which the rows are sorted. If you wanted "Good" ratings to come first, you would want the value of "Good" to be the lowest.

See also related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34977280/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-javascript-using-a-custom-sort-function).

Comment: I wanted to do what OP is asking too, but I've never used code in sheets before. Where does this code actually go? That is, where do I enter it?

Comment: @stevec please complete a tutorial on "Google Apps Script". Google has several of them in their documentation of the product.